# Trying to run powershell scripts from azure automation account to list blob in storage account

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-blob-storage, azure-automation

I am trying to run a powershell script from azure automation account, to list blobs in storage account. This storage account has network rules for selected networks only, tried to provide access keys and SAS into scripts, but still i see 403 error. How can i run my script and list blobs with network restriction?

```
$StorageAccountName = 'xyz'
$key = get-azstorageaccountkey -storageaccountname $StorageAccountName -resourcegroupname "xxxxxx"
$StorageAccountKeyPrimary = $key[0].value 
$ContainerName = 'xxx'
$StorageContext = New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName $StorageAccountName -StorageAccountKey $StorageAccountKeyPrimary
$Blobs = Get-AzStorageBlob -Container $ContainerName -Context $StorageContext | Where-Object{$_.LastModified.Date -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-30)}
$Blobs | ft -property name, LastModified
$totalblobs = $Blobs.Count
Write-Output "Total blobs in container = $totalblobs"
```

Comment: 403 is forbidden, so it's more likely to be a SAS issue than a network issue.

Comment: I tried to add SAS as well instead of primary key, still same issue.

Comment: Have you tried connecting with the SAS through Azure Storage Explorer? SAS keys are notoriously difficult to use. Sometimes you need to URL encode them and you need to use the correct segment

Answer (score 0):

Following code should work. Note that you should enter the Access key also within the code

```
$StorageAccountName = "name"
$StorageAccountKeyPrimary = "your key" 
$ContainerName = "container name"
$StorageContext = New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName $StorageAccountName -StorageAccountKey $StorageAccountKeyPrimary
$Blobs = Get-AzStorageBlob -Container $ContainerName -Context $StorageContext | Where-Object{$_.LastModified.Date -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-30)}
$Blobs | ft -property name, LastModified
$totalblobs = $Blobs.Count
Write-Output "Total blobs in container = $totalblobs"
```

Comment: This is pretty much identical to the original code. What is the difference in this that's going to make it work?

Comment: Access key has given directly in the code and that makes a difference

Answer (score 0):

I have recreated this issue on my subscription and got the below error.

```
This request is not authorized to perform this operation. HTTP Status Code: 403 - HTTP Error Message: This request is not authorized to perform this operation.
ErrorCode: AuthorizationFailure
ErrorMessage: This request is not authorized to perform this operation.
```

When I removed the IP whitelisting I was able to access the blob. Looking at a similar issue online it seems [LINK](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/1d2ad7a3-e221-478b-b495-3677aa847e8a/ip-address-associated-with-azure-automation-script?forum=azureautomation) that you will need to whitelist all the IPs from the Azure data centers as suggested in the link.

Comment: I am not supposed to add all those ip's, will receive violation.

Comment: @Adityac you may post the actual error message you receive so that others can understand the issue better

Comment: This request is not authorized to perform this operation. HTTP Status Code: 403 - HTTP Error Message: This request is not authorized to perform this operation.
ErrorCode: AuthorizationFailure
ErrorMessage: This request is not authorized to perform this operation.
RequestId: 0000-000-000-0000-0000000000000
Time: Fri, 09 Jul 2021 14:03:52 GMT

Comment: @Adityac
Also, check if there are some missing permissions to list the blobs. 
Select Access Policy under the settings blade of the container, and click Add Policy. Select the permissions which you want to give this specific container. Also, public access level is container level.

Comment: @ManuPhilip I am still getting same error even after following above suggestion. I made my container access level from private to container.